# LAMP and default file permissions when apache2 create files

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp

Where can I change the default file permissions that apache2 set for a file when its created or edited ?

**I currently have to run**

```
#!/bin/sh
chown -R username:www-data .
find . -type f | xargs chmod 664
find ./bin -type f | xargs chmod 775
find . -type d | xargs chmod 775
find . -type d | xargs chmod +s
umask 0002
```

*to fix my file permissions, after Apache2 have created a file.*

all my files in /var/www/html need to have this permissions set up:

```
drwsrwsr-x  2 username www-data
```

for everything to work smothly

But all files created by apache have this permission set up:

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 www-data www-data
```

- **Note:** This is a dev server, so security at this point is not the highest priority. I use the box for learning, and its accessible only locally. *But if I do something wrong in my approach, then a heads up is appreciated*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem, was to set up a viritualhost for my domainname. whit **mpm_itk_module** Enabled.

My etch/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.conf file looks like this:

```
ServerAdmin admin@email.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domainname.com
ServerAlias domainname.com
DocumentRoot /URL/TO/HOME/username/public_html
<Directory /URL/TO/HOME/username/public_html/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId username username
</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

and run

sudo service apache2 reload

and everything worked as intended.